# multiple Edittext to display on TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Android Studio so I decided to practice doing some programming on it. The program has Edit texts that ask for three runners name and their time and display it on a textView as first place:... second place: third place:...  but when I run the program, I only get one name from the first edittext. i.e first place: bob, second place: bob, third place: bob. How do I fix my coding to show the other names?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //sets the submit button after entering names and times
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final double time1 = Double.parseDouble(fTime.getText().toString());
            final double time2 = Double.parseDouble(sTime.getText().toString());
            final double time3 = Double.parseDouble(tTime.getText().toString());
            String runner1 = fRunner.getText().toString(); //first runner
            String runner2 = sRunner.getText().toString(); //second runner
            String runner3 = tRunner.getText().toString(); //third runner

            if(time1 > time2 && time1 > time3){
                if(time2>time3){
                   textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner1 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner2 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner3);
                }
                else{
                   textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner1 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner3 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner2);
                }
            }
            else if(time2>time1 && time2>time3){
                if(time1>time3){
                    textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner2 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner1 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner3);
                }
                else{
                   textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner2 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner3 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner1);
                }
            }
            else if(time3>time2 && time3>time1){
                if(time2>time1){
                    textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner3 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner2 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner1);
                }
                else{
                    textView.setText("1st Place: " + runner3 + "\n2nd Place: " + runner1 + "\n3rd Place: " + runner2);
                }
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `runner1`, `runner2`, and `runner3` aren't all "Bob"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted here so far. Show us your entire fragment/activity, where this code comes from. I'm guessing the error is there.

Comment: `fRunner`, `sRunner` and `tRunner` are EditTexts that are using the same id? can you show the code where you are doing findViewById() and the layout? I think they have the same id or you mistakenly using the id for `bob` on the other 2

Comment: You should make sure that fRunner, sRunner and tRunner are actually associated with different EditText elements. Can you post your onCreate method?

Comment: @AndreiVerdes yes! I totally missed that! I had all the editTexts set to fRunner! My code is working! Now I think the if/else is unorganized because it is listing the highest timed runner as first place

Comment: You can get rid of the ifs using a `TreeMap<Double, String>` and mapping the time to the runner's name then using an iterator you could print them. Being a TreeMap, it would save your keys in an ascending order...so you'd print them in the right way.
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/treemap-in-java-with-example/

Comment: Thank for the help! Ill look into it @AndreiVerdes